# scikitlearn SVR giving same values for predictions (have tried scaling)

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression, svm

I have a battery dataframe with rows representing various cycles and a set of features for that cycle:

As an example row 1:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Ecell_V', 'I_mA', 'EnergyCharge_W_h', 'QCharge_mA_h',
       'EnergyDischarge_W_h', 'QDischarge_mA_h', 'Temperature__C',
       'cycleNumber', 'SOH', 'Cell'])
df.loc[0] = [3.730646, 2988.8713, 0.185061, 49.724845, 0.0, 0.0, 27.5, 2, 0.99, 'VAH11']
```

There are 600,000 rows

I am trying to predict the value for SOH as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression # for building a linear regression model
from sklearn.svm import SVR # for building SVR model
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

train_data = pd.read_csv("train_data.csv")
train_cell = train_data.pop('Cell')

# reduce size of df train for comp purposes
train_data = train_data.iloc[::20, :]
train_data = train_data.reset_index(drop=True)

#remove unwanted features
train_data.pop('Ns')
train_data.pop('time_s')

#scale the data
scaler = MinMaxScaler()
train_data_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(train_data)

#return to df
train_data_scaled = pd.DataFrame(train_data_scaled, columns=['Ecell_V', 'I_mA', 'EnergyCharge_W_h', 'QCharge_mA_h',
       'EnergyDischarge_W_h', 'QDischarge_mA_h', 'Temperature__C',
       'cycleNumber', 'SOH'])

train_data_scaled

#unscale target
train_data_scaled['SOH'] = train_data['SOH']
train_data_scaled

#split target and input
X = train_data_scaled.drop('SOH', axis=1)
y = train_data_scaled['SOH'].values

#model
model = SVR(kernel='rbf', C=100, epsilon=1)
svr = model.fit(X, y)

#predict model

pred = model.predict(X)
```

Now returning ``` pred `` gives the same prediction for each row:

```
array([0.89976814, 0.89976814, 0.89976814, ..., 0.89976814, 0.89976814,
       0.89976814])
```

why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

Using `StandardScaler()` on the X and y data corrected this issue, with an inverse called to return it to original values.